# Json_Encode + include/require + Flex + Wordpress PHP?

Tags: php, apache-flex, include, mxml, json

I want my Wordpress user to login and I can put their username as a $variable in Header.php then use json_encode in (json_tutorial.php) to call it onto my flex app, Json_tutorial.mxml

this is my short version of ... json_tutorial.php

```
    <?php

    require_once ('header.php');     //works without this, but doesn't work with this     

    $surname = '$variable';               // $variable = 'doe'; from header.php

    $p = array ('first_name' => john, 'last_name' => $surname);

    echo json_encode($p);            // prints out john doe

    ?>
```

the files Json_tutorial.mxml and Json_tutorial.php are from http://sadhas.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/flex-php-transmitting-data-using-json/#wrapper

I want to know why this doesn't work with the Include or Require?

Also how I can call the variable from header.php to json_tutorial.php to be json_encode onto my flex app?

Thank I really appreciate the help!

Comment: That code example is wrong on several levels, and it's hard to tell whether it's just a copy/paste problem or whether this is your problem. Please define "doesn't work". Your example (sort of) says it does work.

Comment: Yeah I shouldn't have quotes for $variable... I edit that.

It seems like once I have "REQUIRE_ONCE" or use "INCLUDE", it doesn't show up on my flex.

Here is 2 attached screenshots:
http://dnykitchen.com/demo/wp-content/themes/imbalance2/Screen_shot_at_9.09.16_AM.png

http://dnykitchen.com/demo/wp-content/themes/imbalance2/Screen_shot_at_9.08.07_AM.png

Comment: Maybe it just dies because of something in the included file or there's other output that screws up the final output? "Use `include`, don't see data in Flex" is a bit too coarse to answer, you'll have to debug a little more step by step there.

Comment: even when i have nothing inside Include/Require - its breaks.

    require_once ();


is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Enable error reporting, check your error logs, debug the script to see why it fails. `require_once` does not turn off output, it just doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using ob_clean() just before echo json_encode(...).

```
include("library1.php")
require("library2.php")
require_once("library3.php")

$p = array ('first_name' => john, 'last_name' => $surname);

ob_clean();
echo json_encode($p);
```